# How to do a row vector matrix with , in between the components?

Tags: equations, amsmath, matrices

How to add in a comma between row vector matrix?

[image]

I want to have like below:

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}   \\
u_{2}  
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1} & u_{2} 
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{equation}
\bigl(
u_{1} , u_{2} 
\bigr) 
\end{equation}`?

Comment: This is likely to confuse your readers. We use column vectors because maps are written to the left of their argument and because of how linear systems are written down, which prompted Cayley to define “row by column product”. Many people use the convention that (a,b,c) (with commas) actually means a column vector, to save space on the page.

Comment: So, we are unable to use `pmatrix` with a `commas` between the components?